# Java ternary with preference file values?

Tags: android, ternary-operator

Not sure if I have titled my question correctly,  Please let me know  if there is a better title.

I found an open source project that has a few bugs.  I have worked a lot of them out, but a few unique bugs have popped up.

It is a dice game called Farkle, there are several scoring options and 1 of the options is to change the vaule of 6 of a kind.  All works well until you change the preference to 3000 or above.

1st issue - when set preference to 3000 it doesn't recognize that you have rolled a "Farkle" (no score-able die remaining) and does not pass the dice to the next player.

2nd issue - if you roll 6 of a kind (I set it to roll 6ea of 6's) it does show the score of 3000

3rd issue - if it is set to 5000, it shows the score of 3600 and if it is set to 10000, it shows 600.  But... with either 5000 or 10000 selected, it does recognize when you have rolled a "Farkle" and passes the dice to the other player.

I have no clue what is going on, I think a need a rocket scientist to figure this out.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
private final static int isSixOfAKind(int[] array, Context c) {

                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

                String sixKindPref = prefs.getString("sixOfAKindPref", "4x the 3 Of A Kind Value");

                int sixOfAKindMult = (sixKindPref.contains("3000")) ? 3000 : Integer
                                .valueOf("" + sixKindPref.charAt(0));

                int score = 0;

                if (array[0] == 6)
                        score = 10000;
                if (array[1] == 6)
                        score = 200 * sixOfAKindMult;
                if (array[2] == 6)
                        score = 300 * sixOfAKindMult;
                if (array[3] == 6)
                        score = 400 * sixOfAKindMult;
                if (array[4] == 6)
                        score = 500 * sixOfAKindMult;
                if (array[5] == 6)
                        score = 600 * sixOfAKindMult;

                if (sixOfAKindMult > 100)
                        return sixOfAKindMult;
                if (score != 0)
                        return score;
                else
                        return 0;

        }
```

and here is the String Array

```
    <string-array
        name="six_of_a_kind_Array">
        <item>4x the 3 Of A Kind Value</item>
        <item>8x the 3 Of A Kind Value</item>
        <item>3000</item>
        <item>6000</item>
        <item>10000</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: Your logic is just all kinds of wrong here, and your architecture is absolutely horrible.  Treating the first letter of a string preference as a multiplier for a score?  Throw this out and rewrite it from scratch.  Rename it while you're at it-  any function starting with is should return a boolean, not a score

Comment: Gabe,  I have had zero Programming training.  I find things that I think are cool and try my best to hack my way through it.  I think I have A.D.D. as I just can't make it through the introduction of a book without out giving up and I just want to try and do it on my own.  Unfortunately doing it from scratch would mean I would have to know what the heck i'm doing.  But thanks any way, I know I just need to grab a book and finish it.

Comment: Then you'll have a hard time being a programmer, I spend FAR more time figuring out the right thing to do than just doing it-  without spending that time you'll end up just doing it 4 or 5 times.  But think it through-  this function returns a score.  It returns different scores depending on the setting and the value rolled.  Figure out how you'd want it to work.  You may want to simplify it so it works for a specific setting, then come back and make it work for other settings.

Comment: Thanks Gabe!  I appreciate the time you have taken.  Your right, I just need to take the time and learn this and I will be better off in the long run.  Again, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.  I know Gabe won't like it, but it does it work.

```
    private final static int isSixOfAKind(int[] array, Context c) {

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

            String sixKindPref = prefs.getString("sixOfAKindPref", "4x the 3 Of A Kind Value");
            int sixOfAKindMult = (sixKindPref.contains("3000")) ? 3000 : Integer
                    .valueOf("" + sixKindPref.charAt(0));

            String sixOnesPref = prefs.getString("sixonesPref", "10000");
            int sixOnesMult = (sixOnesPref.contains("10000")) ? 10000 : Integer
                    .valueOf("" + sixOnesPref.charAt(0));

            int score = 0;

            if (array[0] == 6) {
                    score = sixOnesMult;
                    array[0] = 0;
            }
            if (array[1] == 6) {
                    score = 200 * sixOfAKindMult;
                    array[1] = 0;
            }
            if (array[2] == 6) {
                    score = 300 * sixOfAKindMult;
                    array[2] = 0;
            }
            if (array[3] == 6) {
                    score = 400 * sixOfAKindMult;
                    array[3] = 0;
            }
            if (array[4] == 6) {
                    score = 500 * sixOfAKindMult;
                    array[4] = 0;
            }
            if (array[5] == 6) {
                    score = 600 * sixOfAKindMult;
                    array[5] = 0;
            }

            if (sixOfAKindMult > 100)
                    return sixOfAKindMult;

            if (sixKindPref.contains("3000") && score != sixOnesMult)
                    score = 3000;
            if (sixKindPref.contains("6000") && score != sixOnesMult)
                    score = 6000;
            if (sixKindPref.contains("10000") && score != sixOnesMult)
                    score = 10000;

            if (score != 0)
                    return score;
            else
                    return 0;
    }
```